# JQ Grid Tool bar search is not working for for Date column

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In jq grid toolbar  searching is not working for date

```
%Q(
    colNames: #{column_array_for_customer(@udfs)}.concat("Created Date","Comments"),
    colModel: #{field_array_for_customer(params[:borrower_id],@udfs)}.concat(
      {
        name: 'created_at',
        index: 'created_at',
        editable:false,
        width: '130',
        formatter: 'date',
        search:true,

        searchrules:{"required":true, "date":true},
       formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'm/d/Y H:i' },
        sortable: true,
        search:true,
        loadonce:true,
        searchoptions: {
           sopt: ['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','cn','nc'],
          dataInit: function(el) {
            $(el).datetimepicker({
              timeInput: false,
              changeYear: true,
              autoclose: true,
              orientation: 'bottom auto',
              onSelect: function() {
                if (this.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                  setTimeout(function () { $("#customers_list")[0].triggerToolbar(); }, 100);
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }
      },
```